# call another method in jQuery Extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var mymethod = {  
    init: function(options){  
    //initialize  
    //how to call buildhtml from here;
    },  
    buildhtml: function(){  
    //build inner html  
    },  
    sendrequest: function(){  
    //make ajax to send request  
    //can I call hoocrequest from here;
    },  
    hoocrequest: function(){  
    //hooc ajax return value  
    }  
};
```

How to call buildhtml or another from init or another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mymethod = {  
    init: function(options){
       this.buildhtml();
    },  
    buildhtml: function(){  
       alert('build');
    }
};

mymethod.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xm5M8/

This method won't work if you're calling `init` from a different context. For example:

```
var fn = mymethod.init;
fn(); // type error
```

In such a case you need to either bind the context to the function reference:

```
var fn = mymethod.init.bind(mymethod);
fn(); // works now
```

Or provide the context when you call the function:

```
var fn = mymethod.init;
fn.call(mymethod); // works now
```

Comment: davin: can I passing a variable from one method to another?